# How to get first name and last name from ContactInformation?

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, contactpicker

I'm using the `ContactPicker` in a Windows Store application, and I need to retrieve the first name and last name separately for the selected contact. Unfortunately, the `ContactInformation` class only has a `Name` property, where both parts of the name are concatenated. The `CustomFields` property is empty.

I find it hard to believe that there is no way to access the first name and last name, since they are stored separately in the Contacts application...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContactInformation` class has been deprecated in Windows 8.1, and replaced by the [`Contact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact) class, which provides more detailed information, including first and last name.

EDIT: actually, this doesn't work; the FirstName property contains the concatenated first and last name, and the LastName property is empty... Not sure if this is a bug in the ContactPicker API or in the Contacts app.

Comment: It seems that the Contact app incorrectly fills the name property of the object.

Comment: @Xyroid, yes, I reached the same conclusion after realizing that it worked fine with another app that manages contacts...