# Windows 8.1 store app contacts returning full name as First Name

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am attempting to retrieve first/last names separated from contacts imported via the Contact Picker. I am receiving the contacts just fine, but the contact object has their entire name "FIRST LAST" in the `FirstName` and `Name` fields.

I have gone into the contacts I am trying to import in the People app and the first name and last name are split properly.

This is true for contacts imported from Google, Facebook, Outlook, or created directly in the People app.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a permission I have to set? Or a setting in the contact picker I need to set?

Edit: Upon further inspection it seems that the People app (built-in MSFT contacts app) is returning badly-formed Contact objects. Does anyone have any experience with this or know if this is a known bug? Also, does anyone know a way around it? Is it still some setting that's wrong? The ContactPicker sample gets the same results I am from the People app, but gets well-formed contacts from itself (and the contact sharing contract).

Comment: [Exact problem was in Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110947/how-to-get-first-name-and-last-name-from-contactinformation). I thought 8.1 will get update in that, but it's not updated :(

Comment: 8.1 was supposed to update it with the new properties, but they appear to have just glossed over it. I'd bet money it's just an update to the People app that we have to wait on, which is annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ContactPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR224913) API works correctly, but the problem is the Contact app, that seems to provide wrong data. In fact, it you try the [Contact Picker app sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1) from MSDN, that implements the Contact Picker contract, you'll see that the information about the selected contact, as returned by the [PickContactAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactpicker.pickcontactasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), are correct.

Instead, it seems that the Contact app incorrectly fills the property of the object that is returns.

Comment: Indeed, that is the conclusion that I came to as well in my edit. I'm going to see about making a bug report for it on Connect and hopefully MSFT can get this fixed. Thanks for helping confirm what I'd suspected!